# How could I mount remote directory to local machine through two ssh hops

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, sshfs

I can access my serve like this:

```
(from local)ssh -p5222 name@server1.com
(from server1)ssh name@server2.com
```

Then I can work on server2.

Now I find I need to mount the folder in server2 to my local machine so that I could use my IDE.

I tried this:

```
ssh -Nf name@server1.com -p5222 -L 2233:name@server2.com:2233
sshfs -p 2233 localname@localhost:~/ ./target-dir
```

But I got this error message:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed read: Connection reset by peer
```

Why I met this trouble and how could I mount my remote file to my local machine please?

Comment: Is the error given when running the `ssh` or the `sshfs` command?

Answer (score 1):

From the commands you run, it looks like the ssh server on `server2.com` is listening on the default port 22:

> (from server1)ssh name@server2.com

If that's the case, then you need to forward the connection towards this port 22.

Instead of:

```
ssh -Nf name@server1.com -p5222 -L 2233:name@server2.com:2233
```

Do:

```
ssh -Nf name@server1.com -p5222 -L 2233:name@server2.com:22
```

Also, in your `sshfs` command, you need to provide the ssh user on `server2.com`, not your local user.

Intead of:

```
sshfs -p 2233 localname@localhost:~/ ./target-dir
```

Do:

```
sshfs -p 2233 name@localhost:~/ ./target-dir
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work, the error message remains same.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried your method, but I got the error message of `read: Connection reset by peer`. What is the reason of this problem please?